# How to label line plot in a combined bar & line plot in ggplot r?

Tags: ggplot2, label

I want to combine a bar and line plot and label line plot.
This is what I got: [plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PnVGS.png)

[image]

this is my code:

```
df %>% 
  ggplot(aes(reorder(NAME, pval),y = pval)) + 
  geom_col(aes(x = NAME, y = pval), size = 1, color = "royalblue", fill = "white") +
  geom_line(aes(x = NAME, y = 10*Ratio), size = 1.5, color="#c4271b", group = 1) + geom_text(aes(label = Ratio))+coord_flip()
```

I want to label line plot, but the bar plot gets the labels?

My second question:
How to rearrange the y-axis from the largest -log(pvalue) to lowest one?

Any help will be really appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try set the `x` and `y` aes in `geom_text()` with the same in `geom_line()`

```r
geom_text(aes(x = NAME, y = 10*Ratio, label = Ratio))
```

Comment: Thank you @yang. it worked. Do you also know how to rearrange the y-axis from the largest -log(pvalue) to lowest one?

Comment: convert the `NAME` to a factor, and set the `levels` according the `pvalue` (in the descending order)